# Can you include large videos files in Android applications?

Tags: android

I was wondering if the Android had any limitations that would prevent 300+ MB's worth of videos to be included in the application?

Currently, I have several iPhone apps that do this, and due to demand, I am looking at the possibility of porting them over to the Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, most Android devices don't have 300+MB of storage space.

Second, Android applications require twice as much space at install time as the app will need when completed, so a user would need 600+MB free (or 1,200+MB free if you turn on Android Market copy protection).

Third, many users attempt to purchase their apps over 3G and will be rather irritated if you cost them a small fortune just for your app download.

Android 2.2 allows apps to be installed to the SD card. That solves the first two problems, at least somewhat, though the first devices are only getting 2.2 right now.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  

iPhone users are required to have an internet connection to d/l my current apps.  That's an Apple restriction.  I can understand the frustration of needing to download 600 MB's over 3G.

So, if I target Android 2.2+ users, and add a disclaimer recommending using an internet connection to d/l, this will work?

Comment: @pherbio: Hopefully that will work. You'll only know for sure if the complaints start rolling in. There is no option in Android to force an app to install over WiFi. I still would encourage you to find another option besides packaging 300+MB of video in an application -- see James Schek's answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can have the application download the data on the first run. That data could be directed to the SDCard or whichever location has the most free space available.

I have not yet seen a way to get an APK to automatically install the application to the internal memory card and the included data to the SD Card.

Answer (score 0):

It's a really bad idea to do this in an Android app. Most Android devices use external storage cards for large data, and has limited internal storage for apps. In latest OS version 2.2, there is a new feature to store applications directly on external storage, but to support the majority of devices you better make it as a separate download.